# Change color of a pixel with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, pixel

Let say I have this rose (Do not care about the background, only the white leaves are important).

[image]

I transform it to a grayscale picture: 
`grayscaled=cv2.imread('white_rose.png',cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)`

How can I change every white pixel to a red one under the condition the red color (`R=255`) will have the same contrast as the white one has ? Meaning I want to see the white leaves in red color but with the same `L` value of every pixel that in `grayscaled` ?

Comment: Change the color space to HSV and then do the appropriate changes. That way, you will be assured of having a consistent contrast value.

Comment: thank you. But what do you mean by *the appropriate changes* ? @scap3y

Comment: You can refer to the link [here](http://www.tech-faq.com/hsv.html) for more details on the HSV color space. For example, white would have very low S and high V values. You can change the H value there to the one which corresponds to RED and alter S/V value accordingly.

Comment: @scap3y thank you, i will give it a try and let you know

Comment: *You can change the H value there to the one which corresponds to RED*: How to know that `H` of a *whitish* pixel corresponds to which `H` of  red , please ? (yes, I read that article) @scap3y

Comment: Okay, so the way _White_ is interpreted in the HSV space is that it can have any Hue (but the saturation of that Hue is very low) with high brightness (V). Does that make things clearer? I am guessing you haven't had much theoretical background on color spaces so might I suggest reading Computer Vision by Hartley-Zisserman? HTH

Comment: I knew before about HSV colorspace even if I am not an expert with it, but I do not know how to get the H value of a color from the  corresponding H of an other one. @scap3y  because each color is defined in its own angel scope

Comment: You need to play around with this on your own. Read the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) for details. To start: go through each pixel value and match H,S and V values for white. Replace that with the H value of Red with a higher S.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop over your grey image and create a new coloured image by yourself.

For each pixel, you can replace the `R` value of your coloured image with the remainder of dividing of `255` and relative grey value:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('5585T.jpg')
print type(img)
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
new=[[[0,0,255%j] for j in i] for i in img_gray]
dt = np.dtype('f8')
new=np.array(new,dtype=dt)

cv2.imwrite('img.jpg',new)
```

[image]

and with `new=[[[255%j,255%j,j] for j in i] for i in img_gray]` :

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But that way,  white pixels will be changed to red pixels. I rather want to change to recolor the leaves in red, but by red, I do not mean (0,0,255) because the red color intensity must be the same as L value in the gray scale level of the image

Comment: I upvote for the effort, but I can not accept because I see from the result that it is too red (almost dark) in regions where it is almost too white (this means the red must be not too dark in such regions). Thank you very much for the effort to help me

Comment: @Kabyle welcome you can change the value yourself. let me edit!

Comment: @Kabyle and sorry for late answer its because installing OpenCV! ;)

Comment: If we take the leaf in the bottom: in the original image, it is lighter on the right and a little bit darker on the rest. The result is opposite in your second test. I think the right solution is around your idea, however

Comment: @Kabyle yes you need to play with the `G,B,R` values, any way i thinks this answer can be accept!;)

Comment: @Kabyle thanks! as a note if you want to get a pic with more quality you need to create your new values based on all  the colors and dont convert your image to gray!