# How to change the color of pixels with Specific coordinates in Python 3 | OpenCV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, python-imaging-library, pixel

I want to load the image using `img=cv2.imread('....jpg')` and change the colors of the pixels whose:

- x coordinate divide by 2 without remainder.
- y coordinate divide by 3 without remainder

I'm using Python 3 in Anaconda/Jupyter.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like a riddle. Please show your input image, your latest/greatest code and expected result. Thank you.

Comment: from PIL import Image
import sys
img = Image.open('moo.jpg')
img = img.convert("RGB")

white = (255,255,255)

 
width, height = img.size
 
for x in range(width):
   for y in range(height):
       if  img.getpixel( (x,y) ) == (2,3):
           img.putpixel( (x,y), white)
img.show()

Comment: I also tried this(from PIL import Image
import sys

img = Image.open('moo.jpg')
img = img.convert("RGB")

pixdata = img.load()

# change with your color
for j in range(img.size[1]):
    for i in range(img.size[0]):
        if pixdata[i, j] == (2, 3):
            pixdata[i, j] = (255,255, 255)
img.show())

Comment: Please don't put code in comments. It's unformatted and difficult to read. Instead, click `edit` under your question and update all the details in there where everyone can see it and understand your question without needing to search through the comments. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggestion to have a look to these Stack Overflow answers:

- [@fmw42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61981194/13903942) Gives a working source code.
- [@Kasravnd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29125528/13903942)
- [Deepfreeze](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28988980/13903942)

Your are asking how change color of image with:

- x Coordinate is a divisor of 2 (hence no reminder)
- Y Coordinate is a divisor of 3 (hence no reminder)

I suggest you to look at [@Mark Setchell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60053414/13903942) answer here.

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward way is to go through x,y pixels in nested for loops and modify the [Mat image container](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d6d/tutorial_mat_the_basic_image_container.html) whenever there is match with the conditions.

Comment: Could you provide minimal executable source code to test your current solution? Also, the image (or similar) which you need to modify.

Comment: from PIL import Image
import sys
img = Image.open('moo.jpg')
img = img.convert("RGB")

white = (255,255,255)

 
width, height = img.size
 
for x in range(width):
   for y in range(height):
       if  img.getpixel( (x,y) ) == (2,3):
           img.putpixel( (x,y), white)
img.show()

Comment: I also tried this(from PIL import Image
import sys

img = Image.open('moo.jpg')
img = img.convert("RGB")

pixdata = img.load()

# change with your color
for j in range(img.size[1]):
    for i in range(img.size[0]):
        if pixdata[i, j] == (2, 3):
            pixdata[i, j] = (255,255, 255)
img.show())